# VBA - Sort rows based on frequency of text occurrences in column

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to sort a dynamic table by the frequency of string occurrences in a column? E.g. a column might have these strings from rows 1 to 6: Company A, Company B, Company C, Company B, Company C, Company C. After sorting the table, the row order would be Company C, Company C, Company C, Company B, Company B, Company A

| Row Before Sorting | Column Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Company A |
| 2 | Company B |
| 3 | Company C |
| 4 | Company B |
| 5 | Company C |
| 6 | Company C |

| Row After Sorting | Column Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Company C |
| 2 | Company C |
| 3 | Company C |
| 4 | Company B |
| 5 | Company B |
| 6 | Company A |

Comment: Add a helper column using countif(), and sort on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the clarifications in your comments.  The following VBA solution should work for your purposes, simply change the sheet/column references to suit.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SortFrequency()

Dim ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, rng As Range, c As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

For Each c In rng
    c.Offset(0, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, c)
Next c

rng.Resize(, 2).Sort ws.Cells(2, 2), xlDescending
rng.Offset(, 1).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a version of Excel with SORT()? If so an assuming your text values to be sorted are in column B:

```
SORT(B2:B6, -1)
```

Sorting this dynamically is possible without SORT(), but can be challenging. I can dig out my older spreadsheets to see how I did this previously if you don't have SORT().

EDIT: here's one way to this without using SORT(). I'm sure there are others.

[image]

In column B you add this function to get a rank order for each item in column A. You need to drag this formula down for every row with data in column A.

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A$13,"<="& $A2)
```

Now column B has a numerical sort order for each item in column A. There are a few ways to get the sorted list in a different column. For column C I used INDEX() and MATCH(). For column D I used XLOOKUP() with a row offset to match the rank #. They give the same result.

```
INDEX(A$2:A$12,MATCH(ROWS(B$2:B2), B$2:$B$12, 0))
XLOOKUP(ROW() - 1, B$2:B$12, A$2:A$12)
```

The XLOOKUP() has the advantage of being easier for most people to understand. It has the disadvantage of assuming the top row of your list won't change.

Editorial you can ignore: The newer array functions in Excel are complete game changers: SORT(), FILTER(), and UNIQUE(). The make doing thing that should be simple and intuitive just that. And they get Excel to being closer to parity with Google Sheets. Still lagging, but closer.

Comment: The excel version I have doesn't have that function. I'm not allowed to update excel on my work computer either.

Comment: 1) Are your text values in column `A` or `B` 2) is your data in `Sheet1`; and 3) is the column to the right of your text column values 'available' for use?

Comment: @kevin9999 To clarify a bit, the text values I'm referring to are actually names of different companies in my database. Anyway, I know how to change column and sheet references based on your solution if you have one so don't worry about it. Helper columns would also be okay

Comment: There are few ways to do this without VBA. The most common is probably a helper column with COUNTIF() to get a rank # for each item, then using INDEX(MATCH()) to get the sorted order in another column. This works well. You can also do an XLOOKUP() with a row offset and use the rank # to find a match. I'll add these to my answer above. Using VB is fine. It seems like overkill for sorting (imo).